# Cannot launch Microsoft Management Console snap-in from Qt

Tags: c++, qt, process

I'm trying to run a program with another program. For this I use a class QProcess.

Program must be run with administrator privileges. To keep things simple step debugging and lead an example here, I started qt creator with privileges administator.

Now the fun part.

The following code runs the calculator.

```
QProcess * p = new QProcess();
p->start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe");
p->waitForStarted();
delete p;
```

This code works. 
Now another example, which already runs the service window windows.

```
QProcess * p = new QProcess();
p->start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\services.msc");
p->waitForStarted();
delete p;
```

This code does not run the program services.msc. File exists and is run from the command line without any problems.

Why one works and the other not? How to fix?

Windows 7 x86.

Comment: What happens when you try to "run" something like a .JPG file? It *should* open in an image viewer, but I think with Qt it might not. Instead, try running `mmc.exe` passing the .MSC file as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** `.msc` is not an executable file type.

**Long answer:**

`.msc` is what's called a [snap-in](http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/definition/snap-in) for the [Microsoft Management Console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Management_Console).

From the command prompt or even from *Start -> Run* (<kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), running `services.msc` tells the operating system *Hey, run this file with whatever program is associated with `.msc` files.*

That program in particular is called **mmc.exe**, and even when run `services.msc` from the command prompt and look in the Task Manager, you'll see the window actually belongs to *services.exe*.

Try to start either `mmc.exe services.msc` or `cmd.exe /C services.msc` instead.

Comment: It's actually a snap-in for Microsoft Management Console, and should be launched with `mmc.exe`. `services.exe` might work too, idk.

Comment: @Steve You are very correct. Running `services.exe` forced Windows 8 to restart :) Corrected the information.